# app failed to run after plugged in shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3 library,and the same problem with sqflite plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

My app failed to run after i plugged in `shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3` library,and the same problem with sqflite plugin.
Please see the error log

```
[+895892 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +4 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task 
':shared_preferences:extractDebugAnnotations'.
[        ] > Could not resolve all files for configuration 
':shared_preferences:lintClassPath'.
[        ]    > Could not download intellij-core.jar 
(com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.5.0)
[        ]       > Could not get resource 
'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com- 
intellij/intellij-core/26.5.0/intellij-core-26.5.0.jar'.
[        ]          > Tag mismatch!
[        ]    > Could not download groovy-all.jar 
(org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15)
[        ]       > Could not get resource 
'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy- 
 all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
[   +5 ms]          > Read timed out
[   +1 ms] * Try:
[   +1 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with 
 --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get 
full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +3 ms] BUILD FAILED in 14m 54s
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"f780a728-3b3b-464c-a369- 
5f2bb360c086","id":"0","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
[+2903 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48264

You should try:

```
flutter pub cache repair
cd <YOUR APP FOLDER>
flutter clean
```

If this doesn't work try **deleting the ~/.gradle content**

Also try `Invalidate Caches/Restart...`. This can be found in the 'File' section on the top left of android studio.